# Entity Framework and DBContext data retrieval

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API where my repository class that has data hard-coded. I want to modify it to grab the same data from SQL Server database. I created the DB Context class in the DAL folder and a connection string in my web.config file with the same name as context class - MyClassesContext

```
 public class myRepository
{

public myClasses.Type[] GetAllTypes()
{

    return new myClasses.Type[]
    {
        new myClasses.Type 
        {
            typeId="1",
            typeVal = "New"
        },
        new myClasses.Type 
        {
            typeId="2",
            typeVal = "Old"
        }
   };

}

public myClasses.Employee[] GetAllEmployees()
{

    return new myClasses.Employee[]
    {
        new myClasses.Employee 
        {
            empId="111111",
            empFName = "Jane",
            empLName="Doe"
        },
        new myClasses.Employee 
        {
            empId="222222",
            empFName = "John",
            empLName="Doe"
        }
   };

}

public bool VerifyEmployeeId(string id)
{

    myClasses.Employee[] emp = new myClasses.Employee[]
    {
        new myClasses.Employee 
        {
            empId="111111",
            empFName = "Jane",
            empLName="Doe"
        },
        new myClasses.Employee 
        {
            empId="222222",
            empFName = "John",
            empLName="Doe"
        }
   };

    for (var i = 0; i <= emp.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (emp[i].empId == id)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

and my model class:

```
public class myClasses
{

    public class Employee
    {
        public string empId { get; set; }
        public string empFName { get; set; }
        public string empLName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type
    {
        public string typeId { get; set; }
        public string typeVal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my DBContext:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using myClassesAPI.Models;

namespace myClassesAPI.DAL
{
    public class myClassesContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<myClasses.Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<myClasses.Type> Types { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now the missing link here is how do I connect DBContext class. I did a great amount of googling but was not able to find anything relevant. Was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into consideration that everything is configured and working (Connection String, database access etc), in your repository, just make use of your DbContext class. Example to get a list of all Types:

```
public List<Type> GetAllTypes()
{
    //Create an instance of your dbContext Class.
    using (myClassesContext  context = new myClassesContext ())
    {
        //Return all the Type's
        return context.Type.ToList()
    }
}
```

I think you need to read and study more about EntityFramework to get a good understanding on how things work, how you can query your database using LINQ. Here's a great starting point:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

**EDIT**
I use this example of a connection string:

```
<add name="myClassesContext "
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Then, you set the same connection string name in your DbContext file:

```
public myClassesContext ()
        : base(Connection.GetConnectionString("myClassesContext"))
{
}
```

Comment: The thing is, as you can see, in my repository everything is hard-coded, I do not make use of the database.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of a connection string for local SQL Server instance. Take a look again.

Comment: I get an error " System.Data.Entity.DbSet<myClassesAPI.Models.myClasses.Type> does not contain a definition for ToList"

Comment: Did you read the tutorial I posted? It seems you lack a lot of basic knowledge of how entity framework works. Take a time to read it through.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting there

Answer (score 0):

How about using a connection string to the actual DB after specifying the database connection string to which you want to connect to:

```
public class myClassesContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public myClassesContext () 
        : base("connection_string") 
    { 
    } 
}

<configuration> 
  <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="connection_string" 
         providerName="..." 
         connectionString="..."/> 
  </connectionStrings> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's the thing, this part I have no issue with, I need to figure out how to get the data in from the database and map it to my classes

Comment: Why don't us generate the models from the database? Via EDMX? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners